# Downloaded files denied Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, html-framework-7

create an app on cordova and I'm using Framework7. In this application, consult a web server that returns some data to me, including a link to download a pdf material, but I'm getting an error message because I don't have permission to download it includes the website address on the access source at config.xml.

I have the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin installed and in config.xml I configured the following

```
<access origin = "https://www.mysite.com.br/download/" />
<allow-intent href = "https://www.mysite.com.br/download/" />
```

I have already followed several recommendations from other forums, but nothing works.
I always receive the following message: net :: ERR_FAILED (https://www.mysite.com.br/download/myname.pdf)

Could someone help me solve this problem that I have been facing for 2 months.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to solve by creating a more general rule as:

```
<widget ...>
    <access origin="www.mysite.com.br/" />
    <access origin="www.mysite.com.br/" />
    <allow-intent href="http://www.mysite.com.br/*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://www.mysite.com.br/*/*" />
</widget>
```

and a Content Security Policy as

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' mysite.com.br">
```

Take care on the position of files (.htaccess rewrite rules could make you have a hard day ifyou don't check them). I'm quite sure you just check the presence of `external` class on your link in HTML, isn't it?

Comment: thank you very much with a small adjustment it worked

Comment: Great to know it's been useful. You can spread love by marking answer ;)